# Why is this use of piped IO streams in Scala hanging indefinitely?

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, io, pipe

I'm playing around with the stream interfaces discussed in [this blog post](https://www.lihaoyi.com/post/StandardizingIOInterfacesforScalaLibraries.html). I've made what feels like a simple implementation to test out the interfaces, but it is hanging indefinitely when I run it and I'm stumped as to why. Here's the code:

```
import java.io.PipedOutputStream
import java.io.PipedInputStream
import java.io.InputStream
import java.io.OutputStream
import scala.concurrent.{Future, Promise, Await}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.collection.immutable.ListMap

implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10))

def copy(input: InputStream, output: OutputStream): Unit = {
  val buffer = new Array[Byte](1024)
  var bytesRead = input.read(buffer)
  while (bytesRead != -1) {
    output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
    bytesRead = input.read(buffer)
  }
}

def curthread(label: String): Unit = println(label, Thread.currentThread().getName())

trait Writable{
  def writeBytesTo(out: OutputStream): Unit
}

trait Readable extends Writable{
  def readBytesThrough[T](f: InputStream => T): T
  def writeBytesTo(out: OutputStream): Unit = readBytesThrough(copy(_, out))
}

def convertToUpperCase(input: InputStream, output: OutputStream): Unit = {
  println("convertToUpperCase")
  curthread("convertToUpperCase")
  val buffer = new Array[Byte](1024) // buffer size
  println("convertToUpperCase: input.read")
  var bytesRead = input.read(buffer)

  while (bytesRead != -1) {
    println(s"convertToUpperCase read $bytesRead")
    val upperBuffer = buffer.map(_.toChar.toUpper.toByte)
    println("convertToUpperCase: output.write")
    output.write(upperBuffer, 0, bytesRead)
    println("convertToUpperCase: input.read")
    bytesRead = input.read(buffer)
  }

  input.close()
  output.close()
}

class Put extends Readable {
  private val output = new PipedOutputStream

  def readBytesThrough[T](f: InputStream => T): T = {
    println("Put: readBytesThrough")
    curthread("Put")
    f(new PipedInputStream(output))
  }
  
  def receive(x: Any): Unit = {
    println(s"Put: receive($x)")
    curthread("Put")
    output.write(x.toString.getBytes("utf-8"))
    println("done receiving")
  }

  def receivedLast(): Unit = {
    println("Put: receivedLast")
    curthread("Put")
    output.close()
  }
}

case class Parsed(value: String) extends Writable {
  def writeBytesTo(out: OutputStream): Unit = {
    println("Parsed: writeBytesTo")
    curthread("Parsed")
    out.write(value.getBytes("utf-8"))
  }
}

def uppercase(r: Readable): Readable = new Readable {
  def readBytesThrough[T](f: InputStream => T): T = {
    val output = new PipedOutputStream
    Future {
      r.readBytesThrough(input => {
        convertToUpperCase(input, output)
      })
    }
    f(new PipedInputStream(output))
  }
}

def parse(r: Readable): Writable = {
  curthread("parse")
  val x = r.readBytesThrough(scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(_).mkString)
  Parsed(x)
}

def display(w: Writable): Unit = {
  curthread("display")
  w.writeBytesTo(System.out)
}

val put = new Put

curthread("main")

Future {
    put.receive("foobarbaz")
    put.receivedLast()
}

display(parse(uppercase(put)))
```

This gives the output

```
(main,run-main-0)
Put: receive(foobarbaz)
(Put,pool-11-thread-1)
(parse,run-main-0)
Put: readBytesThrough
(Put,pool-11-thread-2)
convertToUpperCase
(convertToUpperCase,pool-11-thread-2)
convertToUpperCase: input.read
```

So it appears that reads and writes to each end of the piped stream are happening on different threads as they should. Why then is it hanging at `convertToUpperCase`?

Scastie link: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/I9EIOs8NR2mBeLbcqDx2zA

Comment: If you really need / want some efficient way to stream I/O data, I would recommend looking at **fs2** or **ZIO** and maybe **AkkaStreams**. But, note each of these has a learning curve and imply some new concepts like the `IO` data type or actors.

Comment: @GaëlJ looks like the problem in that question was that the input stream was incorrectly sending EOF. In this case the read is hanging entirely, nothing is coming out, so I think it is different.

Comment: Voting to close this question in favor of a new question I asked which isolates the problem much more effectively: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75908870/why-does-writing-a-value-larger-than-the-buffer-size-of-javas-pipedinputstream