# Why does writing a value larger than the buffer size of Java's PipedInputStream cause it to hang indefinitely?

Tags: java, scala, io, pipe, deadlock

This Scala code hangs indefinitely

```scala
import java.io._
import scala.io.Source
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def copy(inputStream: InputStream, outputStream: OutputStream): Unit = {
  val buffer = new Array[Byte](1024)
  var bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)
  while (bytesRead != -1) {
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
    bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)
  }
  outputStream.flush()
}

val os0 = new PipedOutputStream
val is0 = new PipedInputStream(os0)

val os1 = new PipedOutputStream
val is1 = new PipedInputStream(os1)

// write to os0
Future {
  os0.write(("foobarbaz"*1000).getBytes("utf-8"))
  os0.close()
}

// copy is0 to os1
Future {
  copy(is0, os1)
  os1.close()
}

// read is1 to output
val result = Source.fromInputStream(is1).mkString
println(result)
```

but if I modify the input data to be smaller than the 1024B buffer size of `PipedInputStream`, it works i.e. with

```scala
  os0.write(("foobarbaz").getBytes("utf-8"))
```

it successfully prints

```
> foobarbaz
```

What's going on here? Is there some deadlock in the piped stream implementation?

Scastie link: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/131qJRP9Sc6wSVXrqODd2A

Comment: Not sure what puzzles you here. `copy` write 1024 bytes to os, and blocks because there is no more space 

Comment: Also note that you don't have any control over the order of execution of the `Future`s nor your last code.

Answer (score 1):

The PipedInputStream/PipedOutputStream combo is intended for multi-threaded operations where the reader and the writer are used in different threads. Write operations on a PipedOutputStream will block when the buffer is full, so it is not suitable for single-threaded operations like your copy method.

You could just use a StringWriter to buffer output for later use.

Comment: But the reader and writer actually used in copy belong to different piped IO pairs, and the other end of each pair is being written/read in a separate thread. So shouldn't this work?

Comment: I did not understand your code right away, but yes, you are right, this should work. Not a Scala person, but if I write the same thing in Kotlin, it works for me (for arbitrary string sizes). As I understand, the Future {} block runs in an executor with the chosen execution context, so they should be on different threads. Can you print the current thread names in both futures to check?

Comment: If I put debug statements in your playground app, 3 different thread names are printed, but it never enters the copy method, not sure what's up with that.

Comment: Thanks for verifying it works in Kotlin - I tried it on local Scala and it also worked. So I think this is just an artifact of the Scastie playground. I'll close this question and file a bug report with them.